# Unable to locate google-chrome-stable when trying to build docker image that runs ChromeDriver

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download chrome in my dockerfile so that I can run a selenium script with chromedriver.

I am trying the following code:

```
# Adding trusting keys to apt for repositories
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

# Adding Google Chrome to the repositories
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

# Updating apt to see and install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get update

# Magic happens
RUN apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

But I get the following error

```
==> ERROR [9/9] RUN apt-get install google-chrome-stable                                                                                                   0.5s 
 > [9/9] RUN apt-get install google-chrome-stable:
#13 0.161 Reading package lists...
#13 0.450 Building dependency tree...
#13 0.521 Reading state information...
#13 0.528 E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install google-chrome-stable]: exit code: 100
```

Any ideas?